# Where is akka class Receive defined?

Tags: scala, akka

I am pretty new to the Scala.

In one of the Actor class, i have see my colleague of mine define code like this

import akka.actor.Actor

```
class Processor extends Actor {

  def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: String => doProcess(msg)
    case _ => 
  }
}
```

Where is this class Receive defined ? It is not imported into this class. How will the system find the Receive class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` defined inside the `akka.actor.Actor` companion object and trait respectively.

Excerpt from the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala):

```
object Actor {
    // Type alias representing a Receive-expression for Akka Actors.
    type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
    // ...
}

trait Actor {
    // to make type Receive known in subclasses without import
    type Receive = Actor.Receive
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Receive` is a type alias for a `PartialFunction[Any,Unit]`.  This type alias is defined on the `Actor` companion object which is then redefined on the `Actor` trait (thus available in `Actor` impls) referring to the one defined on the companion.

Answer (score 1):

Receive is a type alias for PartialFunction[Any, Unit]

See the Actor source code [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L328)

You can also write the receive method as

```
def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    ….
 }
```